# glm and cxx-prettyprint, clang: call to function 'operator <<' that is neither visible in the template definition

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, libc++, glm-math

Does anybody use these libraries together? [cxx-prettyprint](https://github.com/louisdx/cxx-prettyprint) and [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/index.html). I'm running into a compile time issue that is being difficult to figure out.

```
    9 #include "Math.h"
   10 #include "UnitTestConfigurator.h"
   11 #include <vector>
   12 using namespace std;
   13
   14 ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const v3& v) {
   15     string s("a v3");
   16     os << s;
   17     return os;
   18 }
   19
   20 SUITE(MathTests) {
   21     TEST(PrintVectorType) {
   22         v3 vec3;
   23         cout << vec3;
   24     }
   25     TEST(PrintVectorofVectors) {
   26         vector<v3> v;
   27         cout << v;
   28     }
   29 }
```

If you're confused by "SUITE" and "TEST", it's because this code is using [`UnitTest++`](http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/UnitTest++.html).

Math.h has in it:

```
# include "../glm/glm/glm.hpp"
typedef glm::vec2 v2;
typedef glm::vec3 v3;
```

Here's the error:

```
In file included from Math.cpp:10:
In file included from ./UnitTestConfigurator.h:26:
In file included from ./util.h:62:
./prettyprint.hpp:212:32: error: call to function 'operator<<' that is neither visible in the
      template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
                        stream << *it;
                               ^
./prettyprint.hpp:295:9: note: in instantiation of member function
      'pretty_print::print_container_helper<std::__1::vector<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0>,
      std::__1::allocator<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0> > >, char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      pretty_print::delimiters<std::__1::vector<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0>,
      std::__1::allocator<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0> > >, char> >::operator()' requested
      here
        helper(stream);
        ^
./prettyprint.hpp:305:23: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::operator<<<std::__1::vector<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0>,
      std::__1::allocator<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0> > >, char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>,
      pretty_print::delimiters<std::__1::vector<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0>,
      std::__1::allocator<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0> > >, char> >' requested here
        return stream << ::pretty_print::print_container_helper<T, TChar, TCharTraits...
                      ^
Math.cpp:27:8: note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'std::operator<<<std::__1::vector<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0>,
      std::__1::allocator<glm::detail::tvec3<float, 0> > >, char, std::__1::char_traits<char>
      >' requested here
                cout << v;
                     ^
Math.cpp:14:10: note: 'operator<<' should be declared prior to the call site or in namespace
      'glm::detail'
ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const v3& v) {
         ^
```

Comment: Ah, the last clang error note appears to be quite clear about how the definition of my `operator <<` should go in the other namespace

Answer (score 1):

This is how to put it in the namespace. Fixed my error.

```
namespace glm { namespace detail {
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const v3& v) {
        os << v.x << v.y << v.z; // super crappy implementation!
        return os;
    }
}}
```